# I can't access my DVR remotely

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, remote-access, remote-connection, dvr

I installed HKVision security cameras some time back. I formatted my computer a week later. Before formatting, I had port forwarded the DVR I.P address, so I could access the live feed and recorded videos remotely perfectly. I can only access them from within the router's private network now. What could I be doing wrong, or be skipping?

***(The DVR I.P address has been port forwarded)***